# How to sort a rollup

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query and data:

```
select * from (
  select provider, title, sum(customer_price) revenue from `100`
  group by provider, title
  with rollup
) x 
where provider is not null
```

This gives me:

[image]

I would like to sort it by the following criteria:

- First, by Provider based on its revenue
- Second, by Title ASC

So, the result should then be:

```
provider                title                   revenue
Electric Entertainment  NULL                    41.95
Electric Entertainment  Leverage, Season 4      31.99
Electric Entertainment  The Cross My Heart Job  2.99
Electric Entertainment  The Inside Job          1.99
Electric Entertainment  The Radio Job           1.99
Electric Entertainment  The Scheherazade Job    2.99
...etc...
```

How would I sort the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
select x.*
from (select provider, title, sum(customer_price) revenue
      from `100`
      group by provider, title with rollup
     ) x join
     (select provider, sum(customer_price) as sum_customer_price
      from `100` p2 
      group by provider
     ) p2
     on p2.provider = x.provider
where p2.provider is not null
order by p2.sum_customer_price desc,
         x.provider,
         title,
         x.revenue desc;
```